# Basic PDO connection to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble testing out this connection, i'm trying to put a test value into the table.

Please take note:

- running Xampp V 3.2.2, both apache and mysql are on and the localhost port is also working well.
- database and table are setup.

---

```
 <?php

 $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost:1842;dbname=mesimot;charset=utf8';
 $db = new PDO($dsn, 'root', ''); 

 $sql = "INSERT INTO mesima VALUES ('', 'first task','0')";
 $count = $db->exec($sql);

 if($count){

     echo 'updated!' . '<hr>';

 }
```

im running login.php on phpstorm and nothing really happens and I check the table and its still empty.
Anything i'm missing?
Thanks

EDITED:
mesima table is comprised of:
ID (AI)
text varchar 25
and bool tinyint 1

Comment: You should test the connection and for that matter test all along the way. Here are some [guidelines](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). If you're on XAMPP you shouldn't have to specify a port unless you have done something odd. You may be able to find your current errors in the error logs.

Comment: I have the port specified and im not getting a 404, but chrome loops when it tries to load logon.php

Comment: You will not get a 404 on port specification for MySQL

Comment: trust me Jay, the localhost is working, also mysql and apache as I have other projects and I use this connection

Comment: I trust *you*, I just don't trust the environment. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9p9b28

Comment: What's the expected result? What's happening instead? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect with a port, use this:

Change,

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost:1842;dbname=mesimot;charset=utf8';
```

To

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mesimot;port=1842;charset=utf8';
```

Notice how I defined the port and how you defined the port?

**Additional Information**

If the queries first value parameter is an auto incrementing ID, then you can leave it blank.

**Edit 1**

Change,

```
INSERT INTO mesima VALUES ('', 'first task','0')
```

To,

```
INSERT INTO `mesima` (`mesi`, `done_bool`)  VALUES ('first task', '0')
```

Comment: Much better! ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hi Script47, thanks for the answer but it's still not working.

Comment: @erezT what happens if you specify a the columns for the table?

Comment: i'm sorry, what do you mean by "specify"?

Comment: @erezT well, in your query add the column fields too.

Comment: @erezT check **Edit 1**.

Comment: same issue, even after edited fix. I run it through chrome reads on the status bar "waiting for localhost"